# Why i am Getting error, while update Composer in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

```
problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.3.18 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.18].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.18 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 5.6.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.6.1].
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.6.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `mbstring` installed with your php.

If you have access to the server, and it's a Linux one, you can install it with

`sudo apt-get install php-mbstring`

Hope I was helpful.